# Not able to sort the data correctly based on their values in Python

Tags: python, arcpy

I Have three columns GDMID, Percentage of overlap post 1 and weight.

1. I need to find duplicate in GDMID.
2. If duplicates found, Check their assign values in Percentage of overlap post 1.
3. Write values in weight column as ('1' and '2') . The higher represents 2 and lesser always represents 1 only.

The code I tried:

```
prevFieldValue = ''
counter = 1
def GetDuplicateCounter(myFieldValue):
  global prevFieldValue
  global counter
  if myFieldValue == prevFieldValue:
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter = 1
  prevFieldValue = myFieldValue
  return counter
GetDuplicateCounter(!GDMID!)
```

But under weight value , higher values sometime represent with '1' only.
So please correct me, where i went wrong. I know this question is too green but require any help.

[Datatable Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEeNY.jpg)

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are changing the value of `counter` based on whether a duplicate is found or not without checking the value in the "Percentage of overlap post 1" column. In this case, the second occurrence of the duplicate will always have a higher weight irrespective of value in the "Percentage of overlap post 1" column. What you can do is to check for duplicate, compare values, then change the `counter` variable. I'm not able to test your code or provide a working one because I don't have `arcpy`

Comment: @Khristos How could you solve this with Python. Here I am not using arcpy module or any module.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know what the format of your data file is and which module will be more appropriate for reading and editing it, I will use an array/list to illustrate how you can do this in python. You can then translate the code to whatever module you'll be using.

Based on the question and comments, I am going to use the following list to illustrate:

```
data = [
 [22505910, 100, ""], 
 [22505911, 100, ""], 
 [22505920,   0, ""], 
 [22505920, 100, ""], 
 [22505921, 100, ""], 
 [22505922,   0, ""], 
 [22505922, 100, ""], 
 [22505925,  45, ""], 
 [22505925,  55, ""], 
 [22505926, 100, ""]]
```

Each sub-list represent a row in the data table, and items 1, 2, and 3 in each sub-list represents the "GDMID", "Percentage of overlap post 1", and "weight" column entries of your data table respectively. The starting weight values for each row is empty, represented by `""`.

Here is the code to provide the weights for each row:

```
prevFieldValue = ""
def GetDuplicateCounter(myData):
    global prevFieldValue
    for row in myData:
        indx = myData.index(row)
        if row[0] == prevFieldValue:
            if row[1] > myData[indx-1][1]:
                myData[indx][2] = 2
            elif row[1] < myData[indx-1][1]:
                myData[indx][2] = 1 
                myData[indx-1][2] = 2
        else:
            myData[indx][2] = 1

        prevFieldValue = row[0]
    return myData

#I tried the above code on the following data:

data1 = [
 [22505910, 100, ""], 
 [22505911, 100, ""], 
 [22505920,   0, ""], 
 [22505920, 100, ""], 
 [22505921, 100, ""], 
 [22505922,   0, ""], 
 [22505922, 100, ""], 
 [22505925,  45, ""], 
 [22505925,  55, ""], 
 [22505926, 100, ""]]

data2 = [
 [22505910, 100, ""], 
 [22505911, 100, ""], 
 [22505920,  50, ""], 
 [22505920,  10, ""], 
 [22505921, 100, ""], 
 [22505922,   0, ""], 
 [22505922, 100, ""], 
 [22505925,  65, ""], 
 [22505925,  55, ""], 
 [22505926, 100, ""]]


print GetDuplicateCounter(data1)
print GetDuplicateCounter(data2)

# Results:
result1 = [
           [22505910, 100, 1], 
           [22505911, 100, 1], 
           [22505920, 0, 1], 
           [22505920, 100, 2], 
           [22505921, 100, 1], 
           [22505922, 0, 1], 
           [22505922, 100, 2], 
           [22505925, 45, 1], 
           [22505925, 55, 2], 
           [22505926, 100, 1]]

result2 = [[22505910, 100, 1], 
           [22505911, 100, 1], 
           [22505920, 50, 2], 
           [22505920, 10, 1], 
           [22505921, 100, 1], 
           [22505922, 0, 1], 
           [22505922, 100, 2], 
           [22505925, 65, 2], 
           [22505925, 55, 1], 
           [22505926, 100, 1]]
```